# How does mongoose schema population work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

is it normal that after I populate a mongoose schema, the result gets console logged to the terminal successfully but doesn't get saved, and instead I get an _id reference to the document that was populated. How can I make sure that the result is saved after population

Comment: This is not a book on how population works, but it probably works as a "for dummies" version of a leaflet: [Mongoose populate vs object nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096822/2313887). Written a while back by myself.

Comment: Okay, i will check it out.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? The question is quite unclear

Comment: after I save a mongoose schema to a collection, I want to populate that schema with a parent schema. Example, I have a Car model, and a Person model; and every person has an array of cars. I want to make sure that for each car saved, it gets added to the car array belonging to the right person. Like an owner property relationship.