# NoSQL for RDBMS users

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am beginners in NoSQL . I am coming from RDBMS database system. I am very confuse how to manage one to many and many to many relationship  in NoSQL and database schema design  I need a proper guideline where i understand the concept  of relational mapping in NoSQL.

If any good book suggestion or any best tutorial .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24096546/8574934) question and [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) page in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In mongo you can create [sub documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) as array . Or if you are creating different collection , then you have to use [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

It is better to learning mongo feature using official [web site](https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/). Because sometimes you get legacy code in tutorial.only you need to figure out the term to search.