# Find specific document and return subarray filtered by populated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Imagine the following scenario:

```
var Almoxarifado = new Schema({  
  descricao: {
    type: String
  }, 
  movimentacoes: [ Movimentacao ]
});

var Movimentacao = new Schema({
  requisitante: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Requisitante'
  },
  observacao: {
    type: String
  }
});

var Requisitante = new Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

where a typical

```
Almoxarifado.find({ _id: 1 }).populate('movimentacoes.fornecedor').exec();
```

would result in:

```
    { 
        "_id" : 1, 
        "descricao" : "ALMOXARIFADO 1", 
        "movimentacoes" : [
        {
            "fornecedor" : 
            {
                "_id": 4,
                "nome": "Arthur Silva"
            }
        }, 

        {
            "fornecedor" : 
            {
                "_id": 5,
                "nome": "Laura Guillioto"
            }

        },
            {
            "fornecedor" : 
            {
                "_id": 6,
                "nome": "Arthur Simons"
            }               
        }           
        ]
    }
```

Now what if I want to get a specific 'almoxarifado' with the array 'movimentacoes' filtered, example:

I would like to execute a 'find' that has the following conditions: 'almoxarifado._id' = 1 and 'movimentacoes.fornecedor.nome' like 'Arthur S'. The expected response would be:

```
    { 
        "_id" : 1, 
        "descricao" : "ALMOXARIFADO 1", 
        "movimentacoes" : [
        {
            "fornecedor" : 
            {
                "_id": 4,
                "nome": "Arthur Silva"
            }
        },
            {
            "fornecedor" : 
            {
                "_id": 6,
                "nome": "Arthur Simons"
            }               
        }           
        ]
    }
```

I can't use aggregation because I need to populate the field 'movimentacoes.fornecedor' and my mongodb version is 3.0, so I'm not able to use $lookup.

Additional info:

- "mongoose": "~4.2.3"
- "mongodb": "3.0.0"

Pay attention that Movimentacao is **embedded** in Almoxarifado and Requisitante is a **reference** in Movimentacao.

Obs.: The solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose) is not suitable for me because the returned array is large (10k+ items) and can't be filtered in memory.

**Question**

**How do I get a specific document in a collection with its subarray filtered by populated data using mongoose Model.find()?**

Comment: I am afraid you can not do it through `Model.find()`, one workaround maybe filter the subarray field after populating.

Comment: @zangw I can't filter it after populating. Please, see my updated question.