# How to display data only which can populate[mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Is possible to display details from collection where has inside population `role: '4edd40c86762e0fb12000002'` ?

```
recommendModel.find({
        userId: userId
    })
            .populate('recommendedBy',{role: '4edd40c86762e0fb12000002'})
            .exec(handle().many.bind(null, 'message', res));
```

So for result where `populate` return null I also don't need record from `recommendModel.find` for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you could perform a filter after your populate in your `.exec`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418489/5737121) answer for more details on the implementation.