# KeystoneJS More Specific Filtering

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

In my Keystone project, I am trying to create a page that shows all posts by an author with a particular name, in this case matching the first name 'Admin'.

```
view.on('init', function (next) {

    var q = keystone.list('View').paginate({
        page: req.query.page || 1,
        perPage: 5,
        maxPages: 10,
        filters: {
            state: 'published',
            author.name.first: 'Admin'
        },
    })
        .sort('+publishedDate')
        .populate('author');

    q.exec(function (err, results) {

    // Use results here

    }
}
```

I have tried adding the following lines to the filters:

```
author.name.first: 'Admin'
author[name][first]: 'Admin'
author: {
  name: {
    first: 'Admin'
  }
}
```

But none seem to work, I'm not sure how to specify it any more than just 'author'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post, but here you go:

I think your issue is that `author` isn't actually the name field type, but is simply a relationship. You need to populate this field, and THEN apply the filter. Have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose) post, which should help you achieve what you're looking for.

As an additional comment, if you're filtering by author, it might be better to use `author.name.full` rather than `author.name.first`.

Also, note that in the mongoose query documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) (which is what `filters` is going to do) there is a similar example and the `name.last` is inside single quotes, so you may also need to do `'author.name.full'` and not just `author.name.full`.