# not able to compare date and get data using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to find only that data, **Availability** date is greater than my current date. where do I put **$gte**

```
function getBookingList(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Booking.find(
            {userId: req.userId}
        ).populate({
            path:'expId',
            model:Experiences
        }).populate({
            path:'slotId',
            model:Availability
        }).exec(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }if(result){
                resolve(result);
            }else{
                resolve({"msg":"Booking Experiences not found."});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I find the today date to compare.

```
 var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));;
 var todaynew = today.toISOString();
```

and I know by using

```
date: {$gte: todaynew}
```

above I can get it but where do I put in my query?

Comment: You likely really mean `.setUTCDate()` there. And unless you did something horribly wrong, then you also don't want it to convert to ISO string, as a `Date` object "should" be what is really expected. And surely then it's just `.find({ userId: req.userId, date: {$gte: today } })`. But you don't even tell us where the date is in your data! Also wrapping in `Promise` is not required. All mongoose methods return a `Promise` already. Simply call `.exec()` without putting a callback in there and the `Promise` is returned.

Comment: all working fine only need to compare with Availability  collection date which comes in populate

Comment: [Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
function getBookingList(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));;
       var todaynew = today.toISOString();
        Booking.find(
            {userId: req.userId}
        ).populate({
            path:'expId',
            model:Experiences
        }).populate({
            path:'slotId',
            match: { date: { $gte: new date() || todaynew }}
            model:Availability
        }).exec(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }if(result){
                resolve(result);
            }else{
                resolve({"msg":"Booking Experiences not found."});
            }
        });
    });
}
```