# how to unwind an array and populate its details in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have `assignments` schema as shown below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const assignmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    document: String,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    trainingId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Training'},
    studentId: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Assignment', assignmentSchema);
```

And `users` schema as shown below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    phone: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And am trying to populate the user details based on the `ids` present in `studentId` Array

```
const User = require('../models/user');
exports.assignments_get_unwindstud_based = (req, res, next) => {
  Assignment.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $unwind: "$studentId"
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": User.collection.name,
          "localField": "studentId",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "studentDetails"
        }
      }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
        }
        res.json(result); 
    });
};
```

But, the resultant `studentDetails` array is showing blank instead of populating and its creating multiple objects for each `training`

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ad4b1394935de1d5064a8bd",
        "studentId": "5ad58e4e151d1b10b850cc16",
        "name": "assignment1",
        "trainingId": "5ad59b231844ba1d60c2c976",
        "studentDetails": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ad4b1394935de1d5064a8bd",
        "studentId": "5ad58fed7c0d6614d80ffda9",
        "name": "assignment1",
        "trainingId": "5ad59b231844ba1d60c2c976",
        "studentDetails": []
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ad4b1394935de1d5064a8bd",
        "studentId": ["5ad58e4e151d1b10b850cc16"],
        "name": "assignment1",
        "trainingId": "5ad59b231844ba1d60c2c976",
        "studentDetails": [
          { ...Student details },
          { ...Student details }
        ]
    }
]
```

[image]
[image]
Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's `"from": "users"` in lowercase, and plural. MongoDB does not know the name of the "Model" in mongoose, and needs the actual collection name on the server. Alternately you can use `"from": User.collection.name` and read the assigned collection name from the model. See [Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688386/2313887) for a usage example

Comment: my collection name is `users` in db and `"from":"users"` is no working

Comment: even `from: User.collection.name` is not working

Comment: did you type it in exactly like that or did you put quotes `""` around it? Note in the comment and the linked example where the quotes actually are. Also if you're going to read the property from the mode, make sure you actually import it in the local scope, or you'll get a runtime error.

Comment: i updated the question.. i have written exactly the same way

Comment: Show the document as it appears in the collection from `"assingments"` and also the expected match  from `"users"`. The only two possible reasons are 1. Pointing at the wrong collection (checked) 2. `ObjectId` values do not match, or are possibly "strings" in one of the collections. Probably best to view the documents from the `mongo` shell as opposed to logging the response from node. We should be able to clearly see the values and type of the data.

Comment: Thanks actually the `student` `ids` were deleted by mistake..now the details are populating. but its creating 2 objects for same `training`

Comment: Of course it is. You did `$unwind` first. You should not need to do that in modern MongoDB releases. Remove the `$unwind` from the start of the pipeline.

Comment: I removed but the `studentDetails` not populating.. my Mongo version `3.6`

Comment: Already asked you to show the documents. You still have not done that. Like I said, there are only two possible reasons aside from coding errors, so you really do need to show the detail. It does work, and many people do this without issue.

Comment: updated the question have a look. is this the document you are asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not clear what your issue here is exactly, so it's probably best to just demonstrate with a self contained listing. You really should not need to change anything in the provided code other than possibly the `uri` for the host and database namespace and maybe authentication credentials.

You should choose a database namespace that is different from what your application is using, as the self contained test here is meant to be destructive of any existing data.

**Modern nodejs releases past 7.x:**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/schooling';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
});

const assignmentSchema = new Schema({
  studentIds: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  name: String,
  startDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Assignment = mongoose.model('Assignment', assignmentSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {
  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    let users = await User.insertMany(
      ["aaa", "bbb"].map(el => ({ firstName: el, lastName: el, email: `${el}@example.com` }) )
    );

    log(users);

    await Assignment.create({
      studentIds: users,
      name: 'test 1'
    });

    let results = await Assignment.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": User.collection.name,
        "localField": "studentIds",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "studentDetails"
      }}
    ]);

    log(results);

    mongoose.disconnect();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }
})();
```

**Or back a few versions:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/schooling';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
});

const assignmentSchema = new Schema({
  studentIds: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  name: String,
  startDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Assignment = mongoose.model('Assignment', assignmentSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

mongoose.connect(uri)
  .then(conn =>   Promise.all(Object.keys(conn.models).map(k => conn.models[k].remove())))
  .then(() =>User.insertMany(
    ["aaa", "bbb"].map(el => ({ firstName: el, lastName: el, email: `${el}@example.com` }) )
  ))
  .then(users => {
    log(users);
    return Assignment.create({
      studentIds: users,
      name: 'test 1'
    })
  })
  .then(() => Assignment.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": User.collection.name,
      "localField": "studentIds",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "studentDetails"
    }}
  ]))
  .then( results => log(results) )
  .then(() => mongoose.disconnect() )
  .catch( e => console.error(e) )
  .then(() => process.exit());
```

You should set that up in it's own project folder with no other dependencies and essentially just `npm install` based on the following `package.json` being present in that folder along with the listing:

```
{
  "name": "schooling",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.0.15"
  }
}
```

So that's really just `mongoose` and it's direct dependencies installed and nothing else.

Either one should give you output along the lines of this:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: assignments.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: users.insertMany([ { _id: 5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb0, firstName: 'aaa', lastName: 'aaa', email: 'aaa@example.com', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb1, firstName: 'bbb', lastName: 'bbb', email: 'bbb@example.com', __v: 0 } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb0",
    "firstName": "aaa",
    "lastName": "aaa",
    "email": "aaa@example.com",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb1",
    "firstName": "bbb",
    "lastName": "bbb",
    "email": "bbb@example.com",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
Mongoose: assignments.insert({ studentIds: [ ObjectId("5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb0"), ObjectId("5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb1") ], _id: ObjectId("5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb2"), name: 'test 1', startDate: new Date("Wed, 18 Apr 2018 10:31:30 GMT"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: assignments.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'studentIds', foreignField: '_id', as: 'studentDetails'
} } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb2",
    "studentIds": [
      "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb0",
      "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb1"
    ],
    "name": "test 1",
    "startDate": "2018-04-18T10:31:30.839Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "studentDetails": [
      {
        "_id": "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb0",
        "firstName": "aaa",
        "lastName": "aaa",
        "email": "aaa@example.com",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad71e821d7f7b05c0316bb1",
        "firstName": "bbb",
        "lastName": "bbb",
        "email": "bbb@example.com",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

That clearly shows you the items from the `"users"` collection are being returned into the array target by the `$lookup`.

If nothing else, this should provide you with a basis to diagnose what is going wrong in your current environment as you can see how things are being done by comparison.