# Re-map an array of ObjectIds in each item of a Nested Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a single document which has user generated `tags` and also `entries` which has an array of tag IDs for each entry (or possibly none):

```
// Doc (with redacted items I would like to project too)
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ae5afc93e1d0d2965a4f2d7"),
    "entries" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b159ebb0ed51064925dff24"),
            // Desired:
            // tags: {[
            //   "_id" : ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d"),
            //   "name" : "Shit",
            //   "color" : "#95a5a6"
            // ]}
            "tags" : [
                ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d")
            ]
        },
    ],
    "tags" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b142608e419614016b89925"),
            "name" : "Outdated",
            "color" : "#3498db"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d"),
            "name" : "Shit",
            "color" : "#95a5a6"
        },
    ],
}
```

How can I "fill up" the tag array for each entry with the corresponding value in the tags array? I tried $lookup and aggregate but it was too complicated to get right.

Comment: Just put up a detailed answer on the same thing the other on the same thing you are asking [Populate Object in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691555/2313887). Using `populate()` really is not the ideal way to do any of this and you really should be using `$lookup`. The post explains why.

Comment: Thanks that IS a detailed answer! I'll take a look soon and mark as dupe if needed

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the vote, I was half inclined to direct dupe but I remembered you had marked self duplicates before. Also just had a serial downvote issue ( no need for detail and hopefully the problem self resolves ) so putting back the subtracted vote there is appreciated. So is such things like marking a self duplicate where appropriate. If there isn't something addressed, then let me know of course.

Comment: Thanks reading now, I had no idea populate was just doing another query and merging 

Comment: @NeilLunn Just looking at this at the mo and pretty stuck, you need a PhD to use aggregate! Any ideas where I'm going wrong here? (I'm sure lots of places) https://pastebin.ca/4039601  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of your actual data, there is no need to `populate()` or [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) here since the data you want to "join" is not only in the same collection but it's actually in the same document. What you want here instead is [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) or even [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to simply take values in one array of the document and merge them into the other.

#### Aggregate $map transform

The basic case of what you need to do here is [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to transform the each array in the output. These are `"entries"` and within each "entry" transforming the `"tags"` by matching values to those within the `"tags"` array of the parent document:

```
Project.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "entries": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$entries",
        "as": "e",
        "in": {
          "someField": "$$e.someField",
          "otherField": "$$e.otherField",
          "tags": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$e.tags",
              "as": "t",
              "in": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$tags",
                  { "$indexOfArray": [ "$tags._id", "$$t" ] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Note there the `"someField"` and `"otherField"` as placeholders for fields which *"might"* be present at that level within each "entry" document of the array. The only catch with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is that what is specified within the `"in"` argument is the ***only*** output you actually get, so there is a need to explicitly name every single potential field that would be in your "variable keys" structure, and including the `"tags"`.

The counter to this in modern releases since MongoDB 3.6 is to use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) instead which allows a "merge" of the "re-mapped" inner array of `"tags"` into the "entry" document of each array member:

```
Project.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "entries": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$entries",
        "as": "e",
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$$e",
            { "tags": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$e.tags",
                "as": "t",
                "in": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$tags",
                    { "$indexOfArray": [ "$tags._id", "$$t" ] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

As for the actual [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) on the "inner" array of `"tags"`, here you can use the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operator to do a comparison with the "root level" field of `"tags"` based on where the `_id` property matches the value of the current entry of this "inner" array. With that "index" returned, the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator then "extracts" the actual array entry from that matched "index" position, and transplants the current array entry in the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with that element.

The only point of care here is in the case where the two arrays in fact do not have matching entries for some reason. If you have already taken care of this, then the code here is fine. If there is a mismatch you might instead need to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to match the elements and take the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) at index `0` instead:

```
    "in": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$tags",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this._id", "$$t" ] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
```

The reason being that doing that allows a `null` where there is no match, but [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) will return `-1`, and that used with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) returns the "last" array element. And the "last" element is of course in that scenario not the "matching" result, since there was no match.

#### Client side transformation

So from the perspective there where you are "only" returning the `"entries"` content "re-mapped" and discarding the `"tags"` from the root of the document, the aggregation process where possible is the better option since the server only returns the elements you actually want.

If you cannot do that or otherwise really don't care if the existing `"tags"` element is also returned, then aggregation transformation is really not necessary here at all. In fact the "server" need not do anything, and probably *"should not"* considering all the data is already in the document and "additional" transforms is just adding to the document size.

So this is all actually possible to do with the result once returned to the client, and for a simple transformation of the document just the same as was demonstrated with the above aggregation pipeline examples the only code you actually need is:

```
let results = await Project.find().lean();

results = results.map(({ entries, tags, ...r }) =>
  ({
    ...r,
    entries: entries.map(({ tags: etags, ...e }) =>
      ({
        ...e,
        tags: etags.map( tid => tags.find(t => t._id.equals(tid)) )
      })
    ),
    // tags
  })
);
```

This gives you exactly the same results and even optionally keep the `tags` in there by removing the comment. It's even basically "exactly the same process" of using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on each array in order to do the transformation of each one.

The syntax to "merge" is much more simple with modern JavaScript [object spread operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), and overall the language is far less terse. You use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in order to "lookup" the matching content of the two arrays for `tags` and the only other thing to be aware of is the [`ObjectId.equals()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/ObjectID.html#equals) method, which is needed to actually compare these two values and built in to the returned types anyway.

Of course since you are "transforming" the documents, in order to make this possible you use [`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) on any mongoose operation returning the results to manipulate so the data returned is in fact plain JavaScript objects rather than Mongoose `Document` types bound to the schema, which is the default return.

#### Conclusion and Demonstration

The general lesson here is that if you are looking to "reduce data" in the returned response, then the `aggregate()` method is for you. If however you decide that you want the "whole" document data anyway and just want to "augment" these other array entries in the response, then just take the data back to the "client" and transform it there instead. Ideally as "frontward" as possible considering that "additions" are just adding weight to the payload response in this case.

A full demonstration listing would be:

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const tagSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  color: String
});

const projectSchema = new Schema({
  entries: [],
  tags: [tagSchema]
});

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    let db = conn.connections[0].db;

    let { version } = await db.command({ buildInfo: 1 });
    version = parseFloat(version.match(new RegExp(/(?:(?!-).)*/))[0]);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    await Project.insertMany(data);

    let pipeline = [
      { "$project": {
        "entries": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$entries",
            "as": "e",
            "in": {
              "someField": "$$e.someField",
              "otherField": "$$e.otherField",
              "tags": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$e.tags",
                  "as": "t",
                  "in": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$tags",
                      { "$indexOfArray": [ "$tags._id", "$$t" ] }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }}
    ];

    let other = [
      {
        ...(({ $project: { entries: { $map: { input, as, ...o } } } }) =>
          ({
            $project: {
              entries: {
                $map: {
                  input,
                  as,
                  in: {
                    "$mergeObjects": [ "$$e", { tags: o.in.tags } ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          })
        )(pipeline[0])
      }
    ];

    let tests = [
      { name: 'Standard $project $map', pipeline },
      ...(version >= 3.6) ?
        [{ name: 'With $mergeObjects', pipeline: other }] : []
    ];

    for ( let { name, pipeline } of tests ) {
      let results = await Project.aggregate(pipeline);
      log({ name, results });
    }


    // Client Manipulation

    let results = await Project.find().lean();

    results = results.map(({ entries, tags, ...r }) =>
      ({
        ...r,
        entries: entries.map(({ tags: etags, ...e }) =>
          ({
            ...e,
            tags: etags.map( tid => tags.find(t => t._id.equals(tid)) )
          })
        )
      })
    );

    log({ name: 'Client re-map', results });

    mongoose.disconnect();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})();

// Data

const data =[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ae5afc93e1d0d2965a4f2d7"),
    "entries" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b159ebb0ed51064925dff24"),
        "someField": "someData",
        "tags" : [
          ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d")
        ]
      },
    ],
    "tags" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b142608e419614016b89925"),
        "name" : "Outdated",
        "color" : "#3498db"
      },
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d"),
        "name" : "Shitake",
        "color" : "#95a5a6"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b1b1ad07325c4c541e8a972"),
    "entries" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b1b1b267325c4c541e8a973"),
        "otherField": "otherData",
        "tags" : [
          ObjectId("5b142608e419614016b89925"),
          ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d")
        ]
      },
    ],
    "tags" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b142608e419614016b89925"),
        "name" : "Outdated",
        "color" : "#3498db"
      },
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b142ab7e419614016b8992d"),
        "name" : "Shitake",
        "color" : "#95a5a6"
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

And this would give full output ( with the optional output from a supporting MongoDB 3.6 instance ) as:

```
Mongoose: projects.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: projects.insertMany([ { entries: [ { _id: 5b159ebb0ed51064925dff24, someField: 'someData', tags: [ 5b142ab7e419614016b8992d ] } ], _id: 5ae5afc93e1d0d2965a4f2d7, tags: [ { _id: 5b142608e419614016b89925, name: 'Outdated', color: '#3498db' }, { _id: 5b142ab7e419614016b8992d, name: 'Shitake', color: '#95a5a6' } ], __v: 0 }, { entries: [ { _id: 5b1b1b267325c4c541e8a973, otherField: 'otherData', tags: [ 5b142608e419614016b89925, 5b142ab7e419614016b8992d ] } ], _id: 5b1b1ad07325c4c541e8a972, tags: [ { _id: 5b142608e419614016b89925, name: 'Outdated', color: '#3498db' }, { _id: 5b142ab7e419614016b8992d, name: 'Shitake', color: '#95a5a6' } ], __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: projects.aggregate([ { '$project': { entries: { '$map': { input: '$entries', as: 'e', in: { someField: '$$e.someField', otherField: '$$e.otherField', tags: { '$map': { input: '$$e.tags', as: 't', in: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$tags', { '$indexOfArray': [Array] } ] } } } } } } } } ], {})
{
  "name": "Standard $project $map",
  "results": [
    {
      "_id": "5ae5afc93e1d0d2965a4f2d7",
      "entries": [
        {
          "someField": "someData",
          "tags": [
            {
              "_id": "5b142ab7e419614016b8992d",
              "name": "Shitake",
              "color": "#95a5a6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b1b1ad07325c4c541e8a972",
      "entries": [
        {
          "otherField": "otherData",
          "tags": [
            {
              "_id": "5b142608e419614016b89925",
              "name": "Outdated",
              "color": "#3498db"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5b142ab7e419614016b8992d",
              "name": "Shitake",
              "color": "#95a5a6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: projects.aggregate([ { '$project': { entries: { '$map': { input: '$entries', as: 'e', in: { '$mergeObjects': [ '$$e', { tags: { '$map': { input: '$$e.tags', as: 't', in: { '$arrayElemAt': [Array] } } } } ] } } } } } ], {})
{
  "name": "With $mergeObjects",
  "results": [
    {
      "_id": "5ae5afc93e1d0d2965a4f2d7",
      "entries": [
        {
          "_id": "5b159ebb0ed51064925dff24",
          "someField": "someData",
          "tags": [
            {
              "_id": "5b142ab7e419614016b8992d",
              "name": "Shitake",
              "color": "#95a5a6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b1b1ad07325c4c541e8a972",
      "entries": [
        {
          "_id": "5b1b1b267325c4c541e8a973",
          "otherField": "otherData",
          "tags": [
            {
              "_id": "5b142608e419614016b89925",
              "name": "Outdated",
              "color": "#3498db"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5b142ab7e419614016b8992d",
              "name": "Shitake",
              "color": "#95a5a6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: projects.find({}, { fields: {} })
{
  "name": "Client re-map",
  "results": [
    {
      "_id": "5ae5afc93e1d0d2965a4f2d7",
      "__v": 0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "_id": "5b159ebb0ed51064925dff24",
          "someField": "someData",
          "tags": [
            {
              "_id": "5b142ab7e419614016b8992d",
              "name": "Shitake",
              "color": "#95a5a6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b1b1ad07325c4c541e8a972",
      "__v": 0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "_id": "5b1b1b267325c4c541e8a973",
          "otherField": "otherData",
          "tags": [
            {
              "_id": "5b142608e419614016b89925",
              "name": "Outdated",
              "color": "#3498db"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5b142ab7e419614016b8992d",
              "name": "Shitake",
              "color": "#95a5a6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note this includes some additional data to demonstrate the projection of "variable fields".

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly detailed answer! Good that 3.6 allows you to merge with other object, but you're right of course doh, I'm returning that data and need it anyway so might as well do the map on the node server!

Comment: Only thing I'm confused about in the old syntax is some+otherField - you can only return 2 fields along with the mapped item or are they for a diff purpose?

Comment: @DominicTobias It's just a demonstration to show that you specify ALL fields within the `$map` but all that will come out are those where the field expression is not `null`, and of course the alternative is `$mergeObjects` where you don't need to specify anything else. The other point indeed was that if you want the whole data anyway, then it makes more sense to do it in the client rather than "create more data" for the server to respond with.