# Find MongoDB docs where all sub-docs match criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some `Product` documents that each contain a list of `ProductVariation` sub-documents. I need to find all the `Product` docs where *ALL* their child `ProductVariation` docs have zero quantity.

Schemas look like this:

```
var Product = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    variations: [ProductVariation]
});

var ProductVariation = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    quantity: Number,
    price: Number
});
```

I am a little new to mongodb, so even sure where to start here.

Comment: could you post your sample document

Comment: Possibile duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) wrapped around `{ "$gt" : 0 }`:

```
> db.products.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7cae558ff28edda6ba4a67"), "name" : "widget", "variations" : [ { "type" : "color", "quantity" : 0, "price" : 10 }, { "type" : "size", "quantity" : 0, "price" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7cae678ff28edda6ba4a68"), "name" : "foo", "variations" : [ { "type" : "color", "quantity" : 2, "price" : 15 }, { "type" : "size", "quantity" : 0, "price" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7cae7f8ff28edda6ba4a69"), "name" : "bar", "variations" : [ { "type" : "color", "quantity" : 0, "price" : 15 }, { "type" : "size", "quantity" : 1, "price" : 5 } ] }

> db.products.find({"variations.quantity": { "$not" : { "$gt" : 0 } } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b7cae558ff28edda6ba4a67"), "name" : "widget", "variations" : [ { "type" : "color", "quantity" : 0, "price" : 10 }, { "type" : "size", "quantity" : 0, "price" : 5 } ] }
```

It can also take advantage of an index on `{ "variations.quantity" : 1 }`.

Comment: I copied your data, and `db.products.find({"variations.quantity": { "$not" : { "$gt" : 0 } } })` seems to be returning back all three products for me. Maybe because they all contain Variations with a zero quantity, rather than returning products that ONLY have zero quantity variations

Comment: Hmm, actually, when I duplicate your data exactly it seems to work, but my data is a little different, so that is my fault. Turns out I am not using sub-documents, but rather linking to other documents (not sure what the correct term for this is). But my Product schema looks more like:

`{name:String, variations:[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'ProductVariation'}]}`

Comment: Looks like you're using the Populate feature of Mongoose (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). I'll play around with it and see what I can come up with.