# Mongoose populate virtual field with a getter function is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am populating a virtual field in mongoose schema with a getter function.
It should populate the field without any errors but it is throwing error

MongooseError: If you are populating a virtual, you must set the localField
and foreignField options

when we are populating a field with getter then the localfield and foriegn field is not required

```
const DashboardSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId
    }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true } });

DashboardSchema.virtual('TopReports').get(function () {
   return TopReports.find({ userId: this.userId }).sort('-date').limit(10);
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a "virtual populate" with a `sort` and `limit` then that's not actually how you do it. What you created is just a "virtual getter" which is actually returning the result of an async function. You *can* use that, but it's a lot trickier to manage resolving the returned `Promise` and it really has nothing to do with `populate()`, which is where you are raising an error.

There are also different options to doing this.

### Mongoose Virtual Populate

For this which is closest to what you attempted, Instead you want something like this:

```
const dashboardSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

dashboardSchema.virtual('TopReports', {
  ref: 'Report',
  localField: 'userId',
  foreignField: 'userId',
  options: { sort: { date: -1 }, limit: 10 } // optional - could add with populate
});

const reportSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  seq: Number,
  date: Date
});

const Dashboard = mongoose.model('Dashboard', dashboardSchema);
const Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);
```

This is actually almost identical to the documentation example on ["Populate Virtuals"](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) in that the given example there also includes the `options` which are the same as passing options to the populate method itself. When you set `options` in the `virtual` you only need invoke like this:

```
let result = await Dashboard.findOne().populate('TopReports');
```

The defaults set for `sort` and `limit` are automatically applied on this "virtual" field as the `populate()` is performed. If you chose NOT to include the `options` you would just add the options manually:

```
let result2 = await Dashboard.findOne().populate({
  path: 'TopReports',
  options: { sort: '-date', limit: 5 }
});
log(result2);
```

> **IMPORTANT** - Setting the `options` within the `virtual` will **ALWAYS OVERRIDE** any `options` passed to `populate()` as shown above. If you want to use different `options` on different requests, then you call on the method as above rather than defining on the `virtual` method attached to the schema.

That's all you really need do. The definition of course includes `localField` and `foreignField` as well as the `ref` all so the `populate()` call knows where to get the data from and which fields to relate to. There is also an *optional* `justOne` which differentiates between singular and `Array` results, as well as a few other options.

### MongoDB $lookup

The other option here is that MongoDB basically has the same functionality built in anyway, with the exception that this is **single request** as opposed to `populate()` which is actually **multiple requests** in order to return the data from separate collections:

```
   let result = await Dashboard.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Report.collection.name,
        "let": { "userId": "$userId" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$userId", "$$userId" ] } } },
          { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
          { "$limit": 10 }
        ],
        "as": "TopReports"
      }}
    ]);
```

So that's one request with a single response as compared to the "many" `find()` requests actually issued by `populate()`. It's the same result and just used the "sub-pipeline" form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in order to apply the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to the returned array of related items.

With a little work, you can even inspect the schema definition ( including a defined virtual ) from the mongoose schema and construct the same [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) statement. There is a basic demonstration of this "schema inspection" on [Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688386/2313887).

---

So it depends on which suits your needs best. I suggest trying both and even bench-marking application performance.

As a full demonstration, here is an example listing. It inserts 20 things and just returns the most "recent" 10 results in the array:

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const dashboardSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

dashboardSchema.virtual('TopReports', {
  ref: 'Report',
  localField: 'userId',
  foreignField: 'userId',
  options: { sort: { date: -1 }, limit: 10 } // optional - could add with populate
});

const reportSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  seq: Number,
  date: Date
});

const Dashboard = mongoose.model('Dashboard', dashboardSchema);
const Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert some things
    let { userId } = await Dashboard.create({ userId: new ObjectId() });

    const oneDay = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
    const baseDate = Date.now() - (oneDay * 30); // 30 days ago

    await Report.insertMany(
      [ ...Array(20)]
        .map((e,i) => ({ userId, seq: i+1, date: baseDate + ( oneDay * i ) }))
    );

    // Virtual populate
    let popresult = await Dashboard.findOne().populate('TopReports');
    log(popresult);


    // Aggregate $lookup
    let result = await Dashboard.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Report.collection.name,
        "let": { "userId": "$userId" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$userId", "$$userId" ] } } },
          { "$sort": { "date": -1 } },
          { "$limit": 10 }
        ],
        "as": "TopReports"
      }}
    ]);

    log(result);


  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

And the output:

```
Mongoose: dashboards.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: reports.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: dashboards.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c572"), userId: ObjectId("5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: reports.insertMany([ { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c573, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 1, date: 2019-04-05T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c574, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 2, date: 2019-04-06T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c575, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 3, date: 2019-04-07T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c576, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 4, date: 2019-04-08T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c577, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 5, date: 2019-04-09T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c578, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 6, date: 2019-04-10T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c579, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 7, date: 2019-04-11T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57a, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 8, date: 2019-04-12T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57b, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 9, date: 2019-04-13T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57c, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 10, date: 2019-04-14T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57d, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 11, date: 2019-04-15T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57e, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 12, date: 2019-04-16T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57f, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 13, date: 2019-04-17T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c580, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 14, date: 2019-04-18T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c581, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 15, date: 2019-04-19T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c582, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 16, date: 2019-04-20T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c583, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 17, date: 2019-04-21T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c584, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 18, date: 2019-04-22T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c585, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 19, date: 2019-04-23T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c586, userId: 5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571, seq: 20, date: 2019-04-24T01:34:22.554Z, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: dashboards.findOne({}, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: reports.find({ userId: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571") ] } }, { sort: { date: -1 }, limit: 10, projection: {} })
{
  "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c572",
  "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
  "__v": 0,
  "TopReports": [
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c586",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 20,
      "date": "2019-04-24T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c585",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 19,
      "date": "2019-04-23T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c584",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 18,
      "date": "2019-04-22T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c583",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 17,
      "date": "2019-04-21T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c582",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 16,
      "date": "2019-04-20T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c581",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 15,
      "date": "2019-04-19T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c580",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 14,
      "date": "2019-04-18T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57f",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 13,
      "date": "2019-04-17T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57e",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 12,
      "date": "2019-04-16T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57d",
      "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
      "seq": 11,
      "date": "2019-04-15T01:34:22.554Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c572"
}
Mongoose: dashboards.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'reports', let: { userId: '$userId' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$userId', '$$userId' ] } } }, { '$sort': { date: -1 } }, { '$limit': 10 } ], as: 'TopReports' } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c572",
    "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
    "__v": 0,
    "TopReports": [
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c586",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 20,
        "date": "2019-04-24T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c585",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 19,
        "date": "2019-04-23T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c584",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 18,
        "date": "2019-04-22T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c583",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 17,
        "date": "2019-04-21T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c582",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 16,
        "date": "2019-04-20T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c581",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 15,
        "date": "2019-04-19T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c580",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 14,
        "date": "2019-04-18T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57f",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 13,
        "date": "2019-04-17T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57e",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 12,
        "date": "2019-04-16T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c57d",
        "userId": "5cce3d9e16302f32acb5c571",
        "seq": 11,
        "date": "2019-04-15T01:34:22.554Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

### The Wrong Way

Just to demonstrate what is wrong with the "getter" approach, here is an example listing showing actually resolving the returned `Promise` on each returned object:

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const dashboardSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

dashboardSchema.virtual('TopReports').get(function() {
  return Report.find({ userId: this.userId }).sort("-date").limit(10);
});

const reportSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  seq: Number,
  date: Date
});

const Dashboard = mongoose.model('Dashboard', dashboardSchema);
const Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert some things
    let { userId } = await Dashboard.create({ userId: new ObjectId() });

    const oneDay = ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 );
    const baseDate = Date.now() - (oneDay * 30); // 30 days ago

    await Report.insertMany(
      [ ...Array(20)]
        .map((e,i) => ({ userId, seq: i+1, date: baseDate + ( oneDay * i ) }))
    );

    // Mimic the virtual populate with the getter
    let results = await Dashboard.find();
    for ( let r of results ) {
      let obj = { ...r.toObject() };        // copy the plain object data only
      obj.TopReports = await r.TopReports;  // Resolve the Promise
      log(obj);
    }

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

And output:

```
Mongoose: dashboards.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: reports.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: dashboards.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5cce45193134aa37e88c4114"), userId: ObjectId("5cce45193134aa37e88c4113"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: reports.insertMany([ { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4115, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 1, date: 2019-04-05T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4116, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 2, date: 2019-04-06T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4117, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 3, date: 2019-04-07T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4118, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 4, date: 2019-04-08T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4119, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 5, date: 2019-04-09T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c411a, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 6, date: 2019-04-10T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c411b, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 7, date: 2019-04-11T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c411c, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 8, date: 2019-04-12T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c411d, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 9, date: 2019-04-13T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c411e, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 10, date: 2019-04-14T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c411f, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 11, date: 2019-04-15T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4120, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 12, date: 2019-04-16T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4121, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 13, date: 2019-04-17T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4122, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 14, date: 2019-04-18T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4123, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 15, date: 2019-04-19T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4124, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 16, date: 2019-04-20T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4125, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 17, date: 2019-04-21T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4126, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 18, date: 2019-04-22T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4127, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 19, date: 2019-04-23T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4128, userId: 5cce45193134aa37e88c4113, seq: 20, date: 2019-04-24T02:06:17.518Z, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: dashboards.find({}, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: reports.find({ userId: ObjectId("5cce45193134aa37e88c4113") }, { sort: { date: -1 }, limit: 10, projection: {} })
{
  "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4114",
  "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
  "__v": 0,
  "TopReports": [
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4128",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 20,
      "date": "2019-04-24T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4127",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 19,
      "date": "2019-04-23T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4126",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 18,
      "date": "2019-04-22T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4125",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 17,
      "date": "2019-04-21T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4124",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 16,
      "date": "2019-04-20T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4123",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 15,
      "date": "2019-04-19T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4122",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 14,
      "date": "2019-04-18T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4121",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 13,
      "date": "2019-04-17T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4120",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 12,
      "date": "2019-04-16T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c411f",
      "userId": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4113",
      "seq": 11,
      "date": "2019-04-15T02:06:17.518Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "id": "5cce45193134aa37e88c4114"
}
```

Of course the `Promise` returned by the getter needs to be resolved for each returned document. By contrast the `populate()` uses `$in` in order to return the matching entries for ALL results in the `find()` with a single request, and this would issue a new `find()` for every `Dashboard` document instead of a single `find()` based on ALL the `userId` values found in every `Dashboard` document in the result.

Basically as opposed to either `populate()` or `$lookup` you are essentially splitting out the "join" logic into parts of the control flow, where it really does not belong, and becomes difficult to manage as well as generating even more requests back to the server.