# Mongoose/MongoDB perform where after populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, where-clause, populate

I am currently facing a problem where I want to retrieve listings from MongoDB using mongoose which a user has not previously liked.

Listings table:

```
const listingSchema = new Schema({
   _id,
   ...etc
})
listingSchema.virtual('listingLikes',{
    ref:'ListingLikes',
    ...etc
})
```

Listing likes table:

```
const listingLikesSchema = new Schema({
   _id,
   listingId,
   userId
})
```

What I want to be able to is perform a query such as this one:

```
ListingModel.find().populate('listingLikes').where({'listingLikes.userId':{$ne:userId}}).limit(10).exec()
```

Basically obtaining all listings where the user has not liked. The following query works to achieve this:

```
Listing.find().where({_id:{$nin:[ ...All previously liked user listings in the listing likes model ) ]}})
```

However this is I believe is largely inefficient (have to load all users previously liked listings into memory before finding the listings).

How can I do this in a more efficient manner? ideally without modifying the current Schema.

Comment: You have the answer here:
[Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose) Hope that helped.

Comment: You have the answer here: [querying-after-populate-in-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose) Hope that helped.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to bring in the `userId` to exclude as a variable, an `aggregate()` with a `$lookup` would likely work:

```
let loggedInUser = 'Eladian'
ListingModel.aggregate([
  {
    // $lookup is instead of .populate() but does roughly the same thing,
    // bringing in the data from the listingLikes table
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'listingLikesModel', 
      'localField': 'listingLikes', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'listingLikes'
    }
  }, {
    // $lookup puts its results in an array in your table. 
    // We flatten it using $unwind
    '$unwind': '$listingLikes'
  }, {
    // $match is equivalent to 'where' 
    '$match': {
      'listingLikes.userId': {
        '$ne': loggedInUser
      }
    }
  }, {
    // limit to 10 results
    '$limit': 10
  }
])
```

Alternatively, you could add a $pipeline to the $lookup, which I believe would be more efficient and allow you to bring in userId from ListingModel or from anywhere else it might be stored:

```
ListingModel.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'listingLikesModel',
      // below assumes there is a 'userId' field in ListingModel,
      // which we put in to a variable (listingUserId) so we can use it in
      // the pipeline
      'let': {'listingUserId': '$userId'}, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$ne': [ '$userId', '$$listingUserId']
            }
          }
        },
        { '$limit': 10 }
      ],
      // It puts the 10 posts in an array called 'notLikedList' in the ListingModel
      'as': 'notLikedList'
    }
  }
])
```

More info on $lookup pipelines [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)

Comment: Is it possible to also "populate" userId or join the user in this same query? Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: Added a second method using pipeline in $lookup which 1) is more efficient and 2) allows you to use userId from ListingModel - which I think is what you meant?

Comment: this still isn't quite right and not what I want to achieve, thanks for all the help so far though. As a better idea I want to perform a query similar to this `Listing.find().where({_id:{$nin:[ ...All previously liked user listings in the listing likes model ) ]}})` but without having to query all a users previously liked listings into memory.

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t efficiency **`cursor`** *(Which is a pointer to the result set of a query)* can be used to extract data of the query results one by one into the the memory and filter:

**Note:** According to `listingLikes` schema the actual reference of `Listings` (by `_id` as `listingId`) is stored, would suggest to tune the `listingSchema` to directly define `listingLikes` as field by `ref`. And not have it as `virtuals`.

As the following solution is in accordance with above. One of the things to note is **`match`** cannot be used directly populating **`virtuals`**.

The idea here is to:

- Prepare a query to populate `listingLikes` for `Listings` with a match on `userId`
- Iterate on the cursor of this query and push docs where `listingLikes [] or null` is empty/null since those will the listings that user didn't like.

*Since `cursors` implement `AsyncIterator interface`, allowing them to be used in [`for…await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) loops.*

```
let requiredListingDocs = [];
//with cursor limit can be removed if it was there to bring only some documents in memory
const cursor = ListingModel.find({})
  .populate({
    path: "listingLikes",
    match: { userId: userId },
    options: { limit: 10 }
  })
  .cursor();
//will contain listingLikes [] empty/or null for Listing docs that user didn't like

//looping on cursor which returns promise
for await (const doc of cursor) {
    if (doc["listingLikes"] === null || doc["listingLikes"].length === 0) {
        requiredListingDocs.push(doc);
    }
  }
console.info("LISTING DATA::", requiredListingDocs);
```

Comment: Would this not do the following? 1) Find all listing likes 2) populate a listings likes 3) ignore all listing likes that are the current users listing likes?

I believe this query would still give me the listings that a user has liked in the results. I need the result to not include any listings that have been liked previously.

Comment: @Eladian If the listing should have a filter as well, that can be put in `find()`, would that not solve it. Can you update the question with some sample `listing` & `listingLikes` docs and what does your expected out look like for a better understanding.

Comment: The best explanation I can give is I want "all listings, which a user has not previously liked". When a user likes a listing a document is inserted into the listingLikes collection. Thus, I need to perform a "not in" form of query. Ill update the question ASAP.

Comment: the listing filter should be `Listing.find().where({_id:{$nin:[ ...All previously liked user listings in the listing likes model ) ]}})`. But in a more efficient way

Comment: @Eladian That clarifies it. I am not sure if this can done with a single query. Have updated the answer with another way to do it efficiently memory wise.